# Setup Stateless Authentication using Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, restful-authentication, jwt

I am using latest version of Spring Boot and I am trying to setup StatelessAuthenticaion. So far the tutorials I've been reading are very vague and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. The tutorials I am using is...

http://technicalrex.com/2015/02/20/stateless-authentication-with-spring-security-and-jwt/

The problem with my setup is that it seems everything is running correctly except for the fact that `TokenAuthenticationService::addAuthentication` is never called so my token is never set and therefore it returns null when the `TokenAuthenticationService::getAuthentication` is called and therefore returns a 401 even when I successfully logged in (Because addAuthentication is never called to set the token in the header). I am trying to figure a way to add `TokenAuthenticationService::addAuthentication` but I find it quite difficult.

In the tutorial he adds something similar to `WebSecurityConfig::UserDetailsService.userService` into `auth.userDetailsService()`.. The only problem I am getting with that is when I do so, it throws a CastingErrorException. It only works when I utilize `UserDetailsService customUserDetailsService` instead...

## WebSecurityConfig

```
package app.config;

import app.repo.User.CustomUserDetailsService;
import app.security.RESTAuthenticationEntryPoint;
import app.security.RESTAuthenticationFailureHandler;
import app.security.RESTAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import app.security.TokenAuthenticationService;
import app.security.filters.StatelessAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
@Order(2)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static PasswordEncoder encoder;
    private final TokenAuthenticationService tokenAuthenticationService;

    private final CustomUserDetailsService userService;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private RESTAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;
    @Autowired
    private RESTAuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler;
    @Autowired
    private RESTAuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler;

    public WebSecurityConfig() {
        this.userService = new CustomUserDetailsService();
        tokenAuthenticationService = new TokenAuthenticationService("tooManySecrets", userService);
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureAuth(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth,DataSource dataSource) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").authenticated();
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint);
        http.formLogin().defaultSuccessUrl("/").successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler);
        http.formLogin().failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler);
        //This is ho
        http.addFilterBefore(new StatelessAuthenticationFilter(tokenAuthenticationService),
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return userService;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenAuthenticationService tokenAuthenticationService() {
        return tokenAuthenticationService;
    }
}
```

The `TokenAuthenticationService` successfully calls the `getAuthentication` method but in the tutorials I read, there is no proper explanation on how `addAuthentication` is called

## TokenAuthenticationService

```
package app.security;

import app.repo.User.CustomUserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class TokenAuthenticationService {


    private static final String AUTH_HEADER_NAME = "X-AUTH-TOKEN";

    private final TokenHandler tokenHandler;
    //This is called in my WebSecurityConfig() constructor 
    public TokenAuthenticationService(String secret, CustomUserDetailsService userService) {
        tokenHandler = new TokenHandler(secret, userService);
    }

    public void addAuthentication(HttpServletResponse response, UserAuthentication authentication) {
        final UserDetails user = authentication.getDetails();
        response.addHeader(AUTH_HEADER_NAME, tokenHandler.createTokenForUser(user));
    }

    public Authentication getAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request) {
        final String token = request.getHeader(AUTH_HEADER_NAME);
        if (token != null) {
            final UserDetails user = tokenHandler.parseUserFromToken(token);
            if (user != null) {
                return new UserAuthentication(user);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

## TokenHandler

```
package app.security;

import app.repo.User.CustomUserDetailsService;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

public final class TokenHandler {

    private final String secret;
    private final CustomUserDetailsService userService;

    public TokenHandler(String secret, CustomUserDetailsService userService) {
        this.secret = secret;
        this.userService = userService;
    }

     public UserDetails parseUserFromToken(String token) {
         String username = Jwts.parser()
        .setSigningKey(secret)
                 .parseClaimsJws(token)
                 .getBody()
                 .getSubject();
         return userService.loadUserByUsername(username);
    }

    public String createTokenForUser(UserDetails user) {
    return Jwts.builder()
            .setSubject(user.getUsername())
            .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, secret)
            .compact();
    }
}
```

In my WebServiceConfig. I add the following

```
http.addFilterBefore(new StatelessAuthenticationFilter(tokenAuthenticationService),
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
```

Which calls on the following class as a filter. It gets the Authentication, but there is No where where it actually adds it.

## StatelessAuthenticationFilter

```
package app.security.filters;

import app.security.TokenAuthenticationService;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Created by anthonygordon on 11/17/15.
 */
public class StatelessAuthenticationFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    private final TokenAuthenticationService authenticationService;

    public StatelessAuthenticationFilter(TokenAuthenticationService authenticationService) {
        this.authenticationService = authenticationService;
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        Authentication authentication = authenticationService.getAuthentication(httpRequest);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null);
    }
}
```

The following class is what gets passed in the `TokenAuthenticationService::addAuthentication`

## UserAuthentication

```
package app.security;

import app.repo.User.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import java.util.Collection;

public class UserAuthentication implements Authentication {

    private final UserDetails user;
    private boolean authenticated = true;

    public UserAuthentication(UserDetails user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

     @Override
    public String getName() {
        return user.getUsername();
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return user.getAuthorities();
    }

     @Override
    public Object getCredentials() {
        return user.getPassword();
    }

     @Override
    public UserDetails getDetails() {
        return user;
    }

     @Override
    public Object getPrincipal() {
        return user.getUsername();
    }

     @Override
    public boolean isAuthenticated() {
        return authenticated;
    }

     @Override
    public void setAuthenticated(boolean authenticated) {
        this.authenticated = authenticated;
    }
 }
```

Thats it...

## My Solution (But Need Help)...

My solution was to set the `TokenAuthenticationService::addAuthentication` method in my success handler... The only problem with that is the tutorial added the class `TokenAuthenticationService` to the WebServiceConfig class.  And thats the only place its accessible. If there is a way I can obtain it in my successHandler, I might be able to set the token.

```
package app.security;

import app.controllers.Requests.TriviaResponse;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
/**
 * Created by anthonygordon on 11/12/15.
 */
@Component
public class RESTAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                        Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
        TriviaResponse tresponse = new TriviaResponse();
        tresponse.setMessage("You have successfully logged in");
        String json = ow.writeValueAsString(tresponse);
        response.getWriter().write(json);
        clearAuthenticationAttributes(request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to call `TokenAuthenticationService.addAuthentication()` yourself when a user supplies their login credentials the first time.

The tutorial calls `addAuthentication()` in `GoogleAuthorizationResponseServlet` after a user successfully logs in using their Google account. Here's the relevant code:

```
private String establishUserAndLogin(HttpServletResponse response, String email) {
    // Find user, create if necessary
    User user;
    try {
        user = userService.loadUserByUsername(email);
    } catch (UsernameNotFoundException e) {
        user = new User(email, UUID.randomUUID().toString(), Sets.<GrantedAuthority>newHashSet());
        userService.addUser(user);
    }

    // Login that user
    UserAuthentication authentication = new UserAuthentication(user);
    return tokenAuthenticationService.addAuthentication(response, authentication);
}
```

If you already have an authentication success handler, then I think you're on the right track that you need to call `TokenAuthenticationService.addAuthentication()` from there. Inject the `tokenAuthenticationService` bean into your handler and then start using it. If your success handler doesn't end up being a Spring bean then you can explicitly look `tokenAuthenticationService` up by calling `WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext.getBean(TokenAuthenticationService.class)`.

There is also an [issue](https://github.com/technical-rex/spring-security-jwt/issues/1) in the tutorial's GitHub repo that will address the confusion between the initial login supplied by the user and the stateless authentication happening on all subsequent requests.

Answer (score 1):

you can define a StatelessLoginFilter like below

```
.addFilterBefore(
                    new StatelessLoginFilter("/api/signin",
                            tokenAuthenticationService, userDetailsService,
                            authenticationManager()),
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
```

and write the class like this

```
class StatelessLoginFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

private final TokenAuthenticationService tokenAuthenticationService;
private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

protected StatelessLoginFilter(String urlMapping,
        TokenAuthenticationService tokenAuthenticationService,
        UserDetailsService userDetailsService,
        AuthenticationManager authManager) {
    super(new AntPathRequestMatcher(urlMapping));
    this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    this.tokenAuthenticationService = tokenAuthenticationService;
    setAuthenticationManager(authManager);
}

@Override
protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain,
        Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {

    final User authenticatedUser = userDetailsService
            .loadUserByUsername(authentication.getName());
    final UserAuthentication userAuthentication = new UserAuthentication(
            authenticatedUser);

    tokenAuthenticationService.addAuthentication(response,
            userAuthentication);

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
            .setAuthentication(userAuthentication);
}
}
```